# HillShade could not find function "overlay" raster package

Tags: r, overlay, raster, terrain

I'm trying to use the hillShade function in the Raster package, and get " could not find function "overlay" " error.

my program reads in a shapefile.
Converts it to a raster. 
uses the terrain function to get the slope, and aspect.
Then when it should be creating the hillShade this error happens: 
"Error in hillShade(fieldSlope, fieldAspect, angle = 45, direction = 180 +  : 
  could not find function "overlay""

if there is anything about the hillShade function and overlay on stackoverflow I missed it. So please feel free to point me in the right direction instead.

the program is as follows:

```
 library(rgdal)
 library(raster)
 setwd("C:/Users/Etching Memories/Documents/Devenshire/Shape/2015/Harvest")
field<-readOGR(".","DEVENSHIRE_Bouge_Big_Harvesting_20151010")

ras<-raster(ncols=40,nrows=40,xmn=min(field$coords.x1),xmx=max(field$coords.x1),ymn=    min(field$coords.x2),ymx=max(field$coords.x2))
rasfield<-rasterize(field,ras,field="Elevation",fun=mean)

fieldSlope<-terrain(rasfield,opt="slope")
fieldAspect<-terrain(rasfield,opt="aspect")

hillShade(fieldSlope,fieldAspect,angle=45,direction=180+45)
```

the compressed shape file  is located at: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/06pfbusfrxun1fr/bouge%20file.zip?dl=0

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this - works fine for me. Have you tried reinstalling `raster`?

Comment: I tried on a different computer and updated the packages as you suggested, and worked fine for me as well. Sorry that I must not have tried updating the package on my pc. Thank you for your help, it saved me many hours of additional agony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jbaums's said, reinstalling the raster package was what worked and is the correct answer.